# Cannot reference a variable in a Common Table Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, dbeaver

This query fails with an error

> SQL Error [137] [S0002]: Must declare the scalar variable "@queryid"

Code:

```
-- create temp table
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TmpTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TmpTable

CREATE TABLE #TmpTable
(
    [id] INT,
    [QueryId] NVARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO #TmpTable VALUES (1, 'hi')
INSERT INTO #TmpTable VALUES (3, 'low')

DECLARE @queryid NVARCHAR(50) = 'hi'

;WITH cte as 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM #TmpTable 
    WHERE QueryId = @queryid 
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

But replacing `QueryId = @queryid` with `QueryId = 'hi'` returns the table

```
1 hi
```

as expected. The [CTE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not indicate that Common Table Expressions cannot reference variables. I welcome fixes that enable the CTE to reference the variable declared before it.

I'm running

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor),
```

and accessing it from DBeaver Enterprise, Version 7.3.0.202012061950

Comment: The code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2045f2c1cdca19d1085723d14649843b.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for trying it. As you say, it runs in the MSSQL 2019 instance you used. That implies some aspect of my environment causes the error. It could be DBeaver or the driver. I'll ask them.

Comment: Are you selecting all the statements and executing it with crtl + enter?

Comment: @Andrew Good catch. No, I've been clicking on "Execute SQL script", or entering option-X. DBeaver's great, but its rules for executing SQL are insanely counter-intuitive, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew found the problem. DBeaver wasn't interpreting all of the SQL. Although it's not discussed in the [DBeaver documentation](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SQL-Execution/), select all -> control-Enter can execute this minimal example in DBeaver.